`eval` in eshell
I've been trying to run ssh-agent in eshell.
From what I understand, when you run the command ssh-agent, it starts the ssh agent and send to the stdout some information that should be incorporated as environment variables.
For example, in bash shell you can use:
$ ssh-agent -s
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-7UtNEMmAhy5o/agent.98196; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=98197; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 98197;

And in fish shell there is:
$ ssh-agent -c
setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK /tmp/ssh-V29WOZoNnJDI/agent.98388;
setenv SSH_AGENT_PID 98389;
echo Agent pid 98389;

Both of them can be used as eval $(ssh-agent -s) and eval (ssh-agent -c) in bash and in fish, respectively.
I found out that the syntax export SSH_AGENT_PID=98197 is accepted by eshell, so copying the information by hand and executing it by myself works.
What I really want is a way to make eshell to interpret the output of the ssh-agent command directly. Something similar to what eval does for the other shells mentioned. Is there something like that?
EDIT:
I am aware that I can open a subshell in eshell using the pattern ${<some_command>}. That is why I am asking specifically about eval, which is the way the other shells handle this and it seems to be the missing part for me.

ssh-agent is supposed to be started at login time - the relevant env variables should be set in the user environment at that point, so that any processes that are created from there inherit those values. Here are instructions if you use systemd - YMMV with other initialization systems, but they are all capable of doing such things. That way, you never have to worry about them in Emacs (or any other program you start in that session).

Interesting point. Thank you!

The eval command in eshell only evaluates Emacs Lisp code. It doesn’t handle the Eshell command syntax.

OK, since there is no eval in eshell (thanks for confirming, @db48x), I went on a different path to solve my issue.
First, I tried to use eshell-eval and eshell-command to interpret the output of the ssh-agent command. I was relatively successful doing that, but the variables set were only accessible in the context of the subshell created by those commands. It means that once the subshells finished the execution, the variables didn't exist anymore. Therefore, the ssh client was still not able to communicate with the ssh agent to retrieve the authentication info.
The only other solution I could think of was to execute the setenv command in the context of the eshell itself. To do that, I had to parse the output of the command ssh-agent, retrieving only the necessary info (SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID). I just needed to tie it to the eshell-mode-hook, so I thought.
The solution looked promising, however it caused an infinity recursive problem. It happens that eshell-mode-hook is used by eshell, but also by its subshells (eshell-eval and eshell-command). To prevent the infinity recursion, I created a buffer-local variable that was set in the beginning of the function, just after its test. Then when the next subshell executed the hook, the variable was already set and the rest of the function was ignored, including the creation of subshells.
Here is the relevant code excerpt that I have in my init.el file:
(defvar eshell-skip-mode-hook nil
  "If non-nil, execute running eshell-mode-hook.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'eshell-exec-mode-hook)

(defun start-ssh-agent-and-set-env ()
  "Start ssh-agent and configure environment variables."
  (unless eshell-skip-mode-hook ; test if subshell should run
    (let ((eshell-skip-mode-hook t)) ; indicate that subshell was executed
      (dolist (p (butlast (string-split (eshell-command-result "ssh-agent -c") "\n") 2)) ; loop over the output of ssh-agent. Last 2 entries are discarded.
        (let ((q (string-split p))) (setenv (nth 1 q) (substring (nth 2 q) 0 -1))))))) ; split each line into tokens and discard what is not needed. ("setenv", ";")
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'start-ssh-agent-and-set-env)

PS: Oh, and by the way, this solution goes really well with the ssh AddKeysToAgent configuration activated.
